# Lazy<> Ninject Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wpf, ninject

I use ninject framework. In my code I have a Lazy object. I can create an instance, but when I call the value property I got an exception.

```
 private Lazy<IPsoriasisReportUserControl> psoriasisReportUserControl;

[Inject]
    public Lazy<IPsoriasisReportUserControl> PsoriasisReportUserControl
    {
        get { return psoriasisReportUserControl; }
        set { psoriasisReportUserControl = value; }
    }
```

I got

> The lazily-initialized type does not have a public, parameterless
>   constructor

exception because the injection does not inject the method into the constructor. I think I have to write a method to the bind what Creates a new instance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Bind(typeof (Lazy<IPsoriasisReportUserControl>)).ToMethod(
            ctx => new Lazy<IPsoriasisReportUserControl>(() =>
                  Kernel.Get<IPsoriasisReportUserControl>()));
```

Comment: This answer works. But you can also do the other answer by simply using the NInject Extension factory. It will work automatically.

Answer (score 13):

Use the factory extension for Ninject https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory

Comment: Actually, a link to the wiki might be the more useful reference than the source code repository, as it shows how the injection of `Lazy<T>` is supposed to happen:
https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/wiki/Lazy

Answer (score 1):

You need a default public constructor on Lazy :

```
public Lazy() {}
```

Comment: there is an parameterless constructor. The injection does not use that I think. Do not know how can I configure that<

Comment: `Lazy` probably refers to the type in the BCL. You'll be hard pressed to change it.

Comment: [TestMethod]
        public void UC_DiagnosticReport_How_Lazy_Works()
        {
            Lazy<IPsoriasisReportUserControl> a = new Lazy<IPsoriasisReportUserControl>( NinjectService.Get<IPsoriasisReportUserControl>);

            var b = a.Value;

            Assert.IsNotNull(b);
        }

this works. I need this

Comment: You have to bind IPsoriasisReportUserControl like this : kernel.Bind(typeof(IPsoriasisReportUserControl)).To(typeof(PsoriasisReportUserControl); BEFORE the bind of Lazy<>