# The lazily-initialized type does not have a public, parameterless constructor. Ninject Lazy Injection Error

Tags: c#, ninject

I Have `Class A` which is a derived type of `ILetter` and `Class B`. I am using `Ninject` as a DI Container. I have used `Lazy<T>` Injection like the following listing.

```
  static void Main()
        {
            IKernel kernel =new StandardKernel();
            kernel.Bind<ILetter>().To<A>();
            var x = kernel.Get<B>();
        }


    public class A:ILetter
    {
        public A()
        {

        }
    }

        class B
        {
            private readonly Lazy<ILetter> _letter;

            public B(Lazy<ILetter> letter)
            {
                _letter = letter;
                var x = this._letter.Value; //Error raise in this line
            }
        }
```

But I got

`The lazily-initialized type does not have a public, parameterless constructor.`

when I call `Value` Property

I followed [this](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/wiki/Lazy) link

I have also seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020736/lazy-ninject-injection) post in which the guy has used method to bind.

which one is true? shall I use the method to bind? if yes, why the Ninject documentation hasn't mentioned it?

Comment: Is the extension really loaded?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I am somehow new two DI and Ninject. what do you mean exactly by loading the extension?

Comment: `ninject.extensions.factory` is an ninject extension, not standard ninject functionality. You'll (presumably, didn't test this exact extension) need to download it and place the dll in the correct directory for ninject to load it.

Comment: I added Ninject with NuGet. shall I download this extension separately?

Comment: Yes the extension is required for Lazy

Comment: Wow Thanks it worked! I installed that like [this](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/3.0.1.0) And I added the ninject.extensions.factory to the output of my project.

Comment: @MehrdadKamelzadeh I updated the wiki so it would be clear to me. Cna you review and/or improve it so it will be clear to you and/or others please?

Comment: @RubenBartelink I will surely do that. Just will you please answer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781885/sample-implementation-of-ninject-extensions-factory-factory-interface) as well? so I be able to edit this wiki too.